# Angular considers instances of specific class as Object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have the following service in angular 4:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {Recipe} from './recipe'
import {Ingredient} from '../shared/ingredient'
@Injectable()
export class RecipeService {

  private recipes:Recipe[]=[new Recipe("Dummy","Dummy","http://media.wiley.com/product_data/coverImage300/2X/04707687/047076872X.jpg",[new Ingredient("French Food",5),new Ingredient("Dummy Book",1)]),
                   new Recipe("jahangiri","a perfect vice president","http://biographyha.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Eshaq-Jahangiri-biographya-com-2.jpg",[new Ingredient("French Food",5),new Ingredient("Dummy Book",1)]) ]

  //do some functionalities

  getRecipe(id:number)
  {
    return this.recipes[id];
  }
  editRecipe(oldRecipe:Recipe,newRecipe:Recipe)
  {
    this.recipes[this.recipes.indexOf(oldRecipe)]=newRecipe as Recipe;
    console.log(newRecipe as Recipe)
  }

  //do other functionalities
}
```

in which *Recipe* and *Ingredient* are classes that are used in app.
I expect that  *editRecipe*  function results in substitution in the intended index.however after substitution *getRecipe* for the inserted item fails.
more examinations revealed that since the inserted item is considered as **object** ,instead of **Recipe** ,although I have done explicit casting,it can not find that .
what can I do?
thank you guys .

Comment: it cannot find object that doesn't exist, you should check if the objects exist first then get the object.

Comment: the intended item exists ,I have logged array to check it,but it has been stored as **Object** instead of **Recipe** so it can not find that.

Comment: What type of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually due to a mistake dealing with form handling.I had to make sure that the fields of FormGroup were the same fields of my class *ingredient* .while I made a mistake there and this is why the argument can not be inferred as **Recipe**
Thank you all guys.

Answer (score 0):

`as Recipe` will not set the prototype it is just a typescript annotation that is removed when it is transpiled to JavaScript. It is only present for type checking.

You could instead use a partial object (or the type itself if you want to make all the properties required) in the recipe constructor like this:

```js
constructor(partial: Partial<Recipe>) {
  if (partial) {
    this.name = partial.name
    this.url = partial.url
  }
}
```

and then in your edit recipe use

```js
this.recipes[this.recipes.indexOf(oldRecipe)] = new Recipe(newRecipe);
```

[Live plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/dvDL80FDhsl4FotqFaiy?p=preview)